# What is the importance for the pressure/velocity at infinity be constant in fluid dynamics?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, boundary-conditions, viscosity, navier-stokes

I am studying fluid dynamics on my own and it is commom to see this assumption. I am asking this here because I didn't find any satisfactory answer. 
For example, I am studying a problem that is as follows

> ''Determine the form of a jet emerging from an infinitely long slit in a plane wall. Let the wall be along the $x$-axis in the $xy$-plane, and the aperture be the a segment in the $x$-axis, the fluid ocupying the half plane $y>0$. Far from the wall ($y\to\infty$) the fluid velocity is zero, and the pressure is $p_0$.''

Comment: The question is not so clear, please add some more information about your problem. If you are studying the problem of an object moving inside a fluid the assumption of constant velocity/pressure at infinity is due to experimental evidence: if an object is falling at 1km distance from you (observer), you don't feel any wind.

Comment: Okay, I've edited.

Comment: It is one possible boundary condition and part of the problem statement. If you want you may assume some other boundary condition.

Comment: 'Far from the wall ($y\rightarrow\infty$) the fluid velocity is zero, and the pressure is $p_0$' Choosing boundary conditions strategically can simplify the solution of a PDE significantly. In this case this specific boundary condition allows the jet to be solved with the use of a [similarity solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Similarity_solution).

Answer (score 1):

In order for a [PDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_differential_equation) (read: the [Navier-Stokes eqs.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navier%E2%80%93Stokes_equations)) to have a unique solution, it is necessary to impose adequate boundary conditions.